# to have + someone + verb form

Tags: experiential-have

I've heard the following in the news:

"They are working with the church community, which has one of its congregation test positive."

1- What is this “have + infinitive” form called ? (I think it is tagged experiential-have, on this discussion group)

2- Is there a web site covering this in detail ?

Comment: Did it actually say "has" - I'd expect "had"?

Comment: @Grismar Or maybe "has had"?

Comment: Your sample sentence isn't grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Syntax: A Minimalist Introduction](https://books.google.ca/books?id=BEgIc4mdj0gC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=%22experiential%20have%22&source=bl&ots=_HUtfRZO_5&sig=ACfU3U36Mdmy9aatuuYp70RXIsCVcVtZTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia89Tjtv_6AhW_hIkEHWB8CbgQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22experiential%20have%22&f=false), that structure is indeed called "experiential have". The only examples it gives are examples of bad grammar, but it's clear enough from the second one what the intended structure is, and it maps exactly onto your example sentence.

I didn't find any resources on it, but the structure is you have described, and it means that the verb happens to the object, and this usually means something bad for the subject. Some examples:

> 1. I had a back tire go flat during the race.
> 2. I had my phone die once during a video interview.

The difference between 1 and the simpler, "A back tire went flat during the race" is the focus that *this happened to the speaker*.

Similarly, with sentence 2 has a feeling of "listen to what happened to me", rather than the neutral story of some event in the past.

The listener is forced to consider how the speaker would feel in that situation, rather than just hearing the story as a fact in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Most native speakers would probably say the cited text is "unacceptable".

I don't want to get bogged down in arguments about whether it's "syntactically valid" or not. At the very least it's hopelessly ugly, and should be avoided. ***In principle***, either of these alternatives work...

> 1: *...which has one of its congregation **testing** positive*
> 2: *...which has one of its congregation **who has tested** positive*

...but ***in practice*** competent writers would normally use Present Perfect for the *primary* verb (and Infinitive for the subordinate verb *[to] **test***)...

> 3: *...which **has had** one of its congregation **test** positive*

Note that the alternatives ***testing*** and ***who has tested*** both work fine with Present Perfect. It's just that the Infinitive is more common (*except* if the "primary" verb is Simple Present).

---

You can tell that ***test*** is an (unmarked) Infinitive because the form of the verb doesn't change even if the subject is pluralized to ***two** of its congregation*.